# Dynamic query: count groups even if row is empty

Tags: 7, database

I have a dynamic query like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->innerJoin('foo', 'f', 'n.nid = f.nid');
$query->leftJoin('bar', 'b', 'n.nid = b.nid');
$query->groupBy('b.nid');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(b.nid)', 'bcount');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'))
      ->fields('f', array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));
$result = $query->execute();
```

I need to count the entries in the bar table for all nid's, which are in the inner joined table of node and foo. If one or more nid's are not in the bar table, I want to count them as '0'. My code only works for the first nid, which is not in the bar table.

What should I add to the code to count them all?

I would welcome every advice!

**UPDATE:**

I just grouped the wrong table I changed `$query->groupBy('b.nid');` to `$query->groupBy('n.nid');` and it works now...

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query you want to end up with? Working out the SQL logic for you would be off topic here, but helping you convert a query you already have into Drupal, if you're struggling, is fine

Comment: Thanks Clive for your fast answer, but I just grouped the nid's in the wrong table. I changed `$query->groupBy('b.nid');` to `$query->groupBy('n.nid');` and then it works...